# Angular 2 components and CRUD

Tags: angular, crud

What's the preferred way of using components with Angular 2 CRUD?

For example, let's say I have a component called `CarComponent`. I might have:

```
CarComponent
NewCarComponent
EditCarComponent
```

(`CarComponent` would handle the list page and deletion.)

Or is it more "normal" to have one single `CarComponent` and handle all the CRUD operations there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I will separate to NewCarComponent and CarListComponent.
In CarListComponent, in template you will have table with delete and edit button inside and one button for create new Car button.
And you need NewCarComponent then create Car and Edit Car button will call to. Cause Create and Edit can use the same template.

Answer (score 1):

The [Angular2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#components) doesn't say anything about this, so I would say that doing either would be okay.

---

**EDIT:**

Upon further thought, you should be creating different components for these different CRUD operations and use `<router-outlet>` to display each component as a child on you main component.